# Does light follow magnetic flux lines?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light

Will light naturally tend to align itself to magnetic flux lines?

Comment: This is a duplicate and the answer is that a strong magnetic field doesn't bend light, but it causes photons to create particle pairs and there would probably be other higher order quantum effects similar to dichroism (i.e. light of different polarizations would have different effective velocity), but none of that would add up to a simple classical bending of light trajectories.

Comment: What do you mean by "align itself" here?

Comment: By align i mean follow the arc of a flux line. thanks